# Unable to fetch results from SQL to Python using mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to query a table stored in SQL using python. I am using mysql.connector package to perform the task.

```
          import mysql.connector


          #Creating a connection
          mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
          host="localhost",
          user="root",
          passwd="something",
          database='mydatabase',
           )
          print(mydb)

          ##Creating a table called customers
          mycursor = mydb.cursor()
          mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE customers (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))")

          #Inserting records to the table
          sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
          val = [
          ('Peter', 'Lowstreet 4'),
          ('Amy', 'Apple st 652'),
          ('Hannah', 'Mountain 21'),
          ('Michael', 'Valley 345')]

          mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
          mydb.commit()
          print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

The problem is when I query the database, there is no output displayed.

```
           query=("SELECT name, address FROM customers")
           mycursor.execute(query)

           for (name, address) in mycursor:
                 print("{}  {}".format(name, address))
```

Here is a link to what I tried and where I got the code from.
Link:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html

Here is the confirmation that the query is storing rows in the database. 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried querying the table via a tool like Workbench or mysqlsh; to ensure the inserted record(s) exist?

Comment: Yes the records exist in the database, it just not showing in python.

Comment: Mate ... I don't know.  I've tested this scenario using 1) my own dataset (`CREATE`, `INSERT`, `SELECT`); 2) your **exact** copy/paste code (except the login creds) in Jupyter Notebook, and 3) your `SELECT` statement on your table created in #2 in console iPython ... and they all work perfectly.  Your code is fine!  I've upvoted the question to help bring some attention.  I don't know mate ... sorry.  Will have a think.  Can you please update your question to show the records **are** in the database?

Answer (score 1):

The code is running fine. The issue seems to be in the line `mycursor.executemany(sql, oval)` as the variable is defined as `val` above. Fixing that should give you the expected output.

Comment: Agree with above.  Just spotted this myself as well.  Good call.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, it was a typo. Code still not executing

Comment: are you getting any error on your console? Did you check if the MySQL table has been created with the entries in your database?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error in the console, Yes I have check MySQL and the table has been created and the entries are present.